# How to pause a while loop in a form

Tags: vb.net

I am running tests on a relay and I would like to add a pause button or hotkey just to temporarily stop the tests however during the loop you cannot interact with the form.

This is for running tests on a relay

```
    Private Sub BTNloop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNloop.Click

        If ComboBox_comport.Text = "Select COM port" Then
            MsgBox("Select a valid COM port")
            End
        End If

        BTNloop.BackColor = Color.Green
        BTNloop.Text = "Started"
        BTNloop.Refresh()
        LblTarget.Text = TxtLoopNum.Text
        LblTarget.Refresh()
        targetloop = TxtLoopNum.Text
        numcount = 1
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        timeon = TxtTimeON.Text
        timeoff = TxtTimeOFF.Text

        loopaction()

    End Sub

    Private Sub loopaction()
        While numcount <= targetloop
            lblposatm.Text = numcount
            lblposatm.Refresh()
            TurnOn()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeon)
            turnoff()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeoff)
            numcount = numcount + 1
        End While
        BTNloop.Text = "Complete"
        BTNloop.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Just want to be able to pause and unpause at any point within the loop

```
    Private Sub loopaction()
        LoopTimer.Stop()
        If serBuf(0) = &H65 Then    'if on then
            serBuf(0) = &H6F                'turn off
            LoopTimer.Interval = timeoff   'stay off for timeoff no. secs
        Else
            serBuf(0) = &H65
            LoopTimer.Interval = timeon
        End If
        LoopTimer.Start()
    End Sub
```

why would this timer not work?

Comment: Since you are doing it on the main (UI) thread, if you sleep it, it will freeze/make it unresponsive. You need to move it to background threads to be able to freely run and do whatever you want with it without freezing the main thread.

Comment: ok i have little to no idea how but i will do some research thanks

Comment: You aren't doing anything computational in that loop.  Just use a timer.  Use a bool variable to skip any processing in the tick event to emulate a "pause" condition.

Comment: ok i will need to use 2 timers though to apply for the on and off right?

Comment: Depends.  You can always switch the interval time depending on what you're doing.  One of the answers below shows that.  Use the @name in comments to respond to someone at this site to give them a notification.

Comment: @LarsTech i have added my timer code but it does not seem to work out

Comment: Timer code would be the code that runs in the Tick event.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do when pausing the code?  Do you want to be able to inspect variable values?  If that is the case your solution is no more complicated that using breakpoints in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a timer and do the things on timer ticks instead of in a loop.

```
Private ReadOnly _timer As Timer = New Timer With {
    .Interval = someMilliseconds
}
Private _on As Boolean = False
```

Somewhere else

```
_timer.Start()
```

And

```
Public Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    _timer.Stop()
    If _on Then
        'Do "ON" things
        _timer.Interval = onInterval
    Else
        'Do "OFF" things
        _timer.Interval = offInterval
    End If
    _on = Not _on
    _timer.Start();
End Sub
```

At any time you can stop the timer with  `_timer.Stop()` or restart it with  `_timer.Start()`.

Also, the .NET Framework has different timers in different namespaces. I don't know which one is best in this case. As @Cheddar mentioned, depending on the hardware and OS used, timers might not work as expected.

Comment: This is a good point. However, if the hardware he is talking about is an Arduino then you have to make sure the arduino clock and vb clock are in sync. Other wise you get some weird outcomes because the arduino is technically working in a loop fashion.

Comment: Ah yes i didnt think of it that way, only downside is that i am running different intervals for turning off and turning on so while loop was my best bet

Comment: You could stop the timer at every tick and restart it with the new interval.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple things here.

1. You could add a message box to stop the code until you hit ok on the message box. Code example as follow:

   msgbox("Pause")

   ```
   Private Sub loopaction()
   While numcount <= targetloop
       lblposatm.Text = numcount
       lblposatm.Refresh()
       TurnOn()
       Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeon)
       msgbox("Pause") 'Notice the added box
       turnoff()
       Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeoff)
       numcount = numcount + 1
   End While
   BTNloop.Text = "Complete"
   BTNloop.Refresh()
   End Sub
   ```
2. You could use a compiler break. In visual studio you do this by clicking on the area beside the number of the line to add a red circle and this will also pause the code.
3. Use the enter key to pause the program.

   ```
   Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

   If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
       MsgBox("Pause")
   End If

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I see however its more of a precaution. It's unknown when it may need to pause so I cannot predetermine it. Its mainly in case something goes wrong so a pause is needed for the hardware.

Comment: Ok you want a hot key to pause? Give me a minute.

Comment: @Brad Check option 3, it should give you what you want.

Comment: Ok after some testing it seems to have no effect. The form is essentially frozen till the loop is complete

Comment: @Brad take a look at the comment up top about putting it on the back threads. I am assuming your using either an Arduino or PI. In this case that loop will run until its through the entire loop before looking for key strokes. I think I have something that will work within the loop.

Comment: @Brad you are going to have to use a dll file to check the keystate of any given key and then check its state in a quick if statement. I have done it before for hardware testing but I cant quite remember how I did it. Ill try and look at it but google "using dll files to check keystate VB.Net"

Comment: ok im going to test timers as that should allow me to use the keybinds thanks